# Iterate over array in Flask

Tags: python, html, arrays, flask

I'm trying to iterate over an array in Flask.

```
{% for list in lists %}
    <div>{{list}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This template is rendering this:

```
<div>
    {'list': '2', 'item': '["a", "b", "c"]', 'created_at': '2020-07-12 17:19:52'}
</div>
```

Now, instead of the whole data, I want to render a `ul` using the items in «item» field:

```
{% for list in lists %}
    <ul>
        {% for item in list.item %}
            <li>{{item}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

But I end up with this:

```
<ul>                        
     <li>[</li>
     <li>"</li>
     <li>a</li>
     <li>"</li>
     <li>,</li>
     <li> </li>
     <li>"</li>
     <li>b</li>
     <li>"</li>
     <li>,</li>
     <li> </li>
     <li>"</li>
     <li>c</li>
     <li>"</li>
     <li>]</li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`list.item` is a string. If you iterate over a string, you iterate, over each character.

You can change the template, so `list.item` is a list by removing the quotation marks.

```
<div>
    {'list': '2', 'item': ["a", "b", "c"], 'created_at': '2020-07-12 17:19:52'}
</div>
```

If you don't have control over the input to change is directly, you can for example use the [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) function to deserialize the string

```
>>> list_items = '["a", "b", "c"]'
>>> import json
>>> for item in json.loads(list_items):
...    print(item)
...
a
b
c
```

Comment: Thanks @querenker! Yes, you are in reason: is there any function to remove this quotes in flask?

Comment: @Alexandra There are multiple function that can be used for this purpose, such as `eval`, `ast.literal_eval` and `json.loads` (each with their benefits). In your case, I would go with `json.loads` and added this to my answer.